# How to make Buttons in LibGDX exclusive

Tags: java, android, button, menu, libgdx

I'm making an app with a menu that utilizes a Stage and 3 Buttons. They all work well, the only thing that bothers me is that when I'm pressing a button I can also press the other ones(the animation still occurs). What can I do so that when I press a button the other ones are disabled?

Comment: Why not just have the buttons have `active` flags that are set to `false` when another button is pressed?

Comment: I tried setDisable(true) when touching a button but the animation still happened when I touched the other ones.

Comment: Then something might be wrong with the listeners you are assigning them. Try posting their code, maybe I can find something.

Comment: Maybe `setChecked(boolean checked)` but there is almost something in Scene2d for that. [ButtonGroup](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d.ui#buttongroup) there you can add your buttons and you can `setMinCheckCount(int count)` and `setMaxCheckCount(int count)`.

Comment: I also tried that but it doesn't work. I set the minimum check count to 0 and the max to 1 but it still doesn't work. I don't know about setChecked and other functions related to ButtonGroup and couldn't find anything in the web.

Answer (score 0):

I created a subclass of Stage to fix this in my game. You can use a separate, standard Stage for non-UI stuff, and use this secondary stage just for the UI.

```
public class SingleTouchStage extends Stage {

    public SingleTouchStage () {
        super();
    }

    public SingleTouchStage (Viewport viewport) {
        super(viewport);
    }

    public SingleTouchStage (Viewport viewport, Batch batch) {
        super(viewport, batch);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown (int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        if (pointer != 0)
            return false;
        return super.touchDown(screenX, screenY, pointer, button);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDragged (int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
        if (pointer != 0)
            return false;
        return super.touchDragged(screenX, screenY, pointer);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchUp (int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        if (pointer != 0)
            return false;
        return super.touchUp(screenX, screenY, pointer, button);
    }
}
```